# Image link with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, random, hyperlink

I am not into javascript, but I really want randomized pictures on my index page so was wondering if there is anything I could do with my current javascript to add image link to each picture?

```js
< img id = "reklame" / >
  < script >
  function getRandomImage() {
    var images = ['bilder/reklame.jpg', 'bilder/reklame1.jpg', 'bilder/reklame2.jpg', 'bilder/reklame3.jpg'];
    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

    return image;
  }

function displayRandomImage() {
  var htmlImage = document.getElementById("reklame");
  htmlImage.src = getRandomImage();
}
displayRandomImage(); < /script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8Lh0hg4o/ ? Its generating random images.

Comment: Now it is only doing it once - you need to add event like click or time interval, something that will call `displayRandomImage()` function.

Comment: What dou you mean by "`imagelink`"? Do you just mean the source of the imagefile or should the image redirect to another page on click?

Comment: I want it to be an image link, as in, when I click on the image, it will redirect me to another page, for example "products.php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your displayRandomImage() inside [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
window.setInterval(function(){
      displayRandomImage();
}, 5000);
```

try this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yellen/twf16y5a/4/

**Fiddle updated to link a url with each image**

```js
function getRandomImage() {
  var images = [{
      "image": "http://freethumbs.dreamstime.com/8/big/free_89634.jpg",
      "url": "http://www.google.com"
    }, {
      "image": "http://freethumbs.dreamstime.com/14/big/free_144227.jpg",
      "url": "http://www.facebook.com"
    }, {
      "image": "http://freethumbs.dreamstime.com/22/big/free_229201.jpg",
      "url": "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    }]
    // You'd like store the image path and the url as a single object and have an array of that 
    //images = [{img, url},{img, url}]
  var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  return image;
}

function displayRandomImage() {
  var htmlImage = document.getElementById("reklame");
  var link = document.getElementById("myuA");
  var imageObj = getRandomImage();
  htmlImage.src = imageObj.image;
  link.href  = imageObj.url;
}
displayRandomImage();
window.setInterval(function() {
  displayRandomImage();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<a id="myuA" href="" target="_blank">
  <img id="reklame" />
</a>
```

Comment: Give interval of your choice

Comment: Thank you, this worked, but am i able to click on the image and let it redirect me to products which is called "product.php" ??

Comment: You can do that by chaging your getRandomImage() function to return an object {image:'path to image', link:'link to click'}

Comment: @TheAsianTutorials - I've updated the answer with a new fiddle that links a url with each image

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) function

```
//First call
displayRandomImage();
var loop = setInterval(function() {
    //Call each 5 seconds
    displayRandomImage()
}, 5000);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lh0hg4o/2/)

Answer (score 1):

hope this will work:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id = "reklame">
<img  / >
</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function getRandomImage() {
    var images = ['bilder/reklame.jpg', 'bilder/reklame1.jpg', 'bilder/reklame2.jpg', 'bilder/reklame3.jpg'];
    var image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

    return image;
  }

function displayRandomImage() {
  var imgDiv = document.getElementById("reklame");
  var image = imgDiv.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    image.src = getRandomImage();
  var a=document.createElement('a');
     a.href=getRandomImage();
     a.appendChild(image);
    imgDiv.appendChild(a);
} 

window.setInterval(function(){
      displayRandomImage();
}, 5000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<a id="reklame-link" href="#";>
<img id = "reklame" />
```

```
function displayRandomImage() {
var htmlImage = document.getElementById("reklame");
var htmlLink = document.getElementById("reklame-link");
var randomImage = getRandomImage();
htmlImage.src = randomImage;
htmlLink.href = randomImage; 
console.log(getRandomImage()); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y7rwhmd7/